# Testing in libGDX with Junit on IntelliJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, libgdx

It's the first time I'm working with libGDX, and I'm coding for a school project a desktop game.
It is requested to implement tests in our project of our model classes, the assignment requires to use jUnit to execute those tests.

I've currently imported the jUnit4 in the build.gradle but when I'm trying to run the tests through the gradle menu inside intelliJ it gave me errors with loading libGDX dependencies.
Looking around I found that I should use an HeadlessApplication, therefore I also added those dependencies in the build.gradle, but now I get another error.
The main issue seems to be with loading textures, here I send you the error message:

```
Exception in thread "HeadlessApplication" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20.glCreateShader(int)" because "gl" is null

...

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: FirePuzzle/page.jpg

...

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: FirePuzzle/page.jpg (Internal)
```

Here it is the test class implementation:

```
public class FirePuzzleTest {
    private Gioco game;
    private FirePuzzle puzzle;
    private HeadlessApplication application;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        game = new Gioco();
        if(application == null){
            HeadlessApplicationConfiguration config = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
            application = new HeadlessApplication(game, config);
        }
        puzzle = FirePuzzle.getInstance();
        puzzle.setUpPuzzle();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        puzzle.setNull();
        puzzle = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void burnPage() {
        int i = puzzle.getToBurn() - 1;
        puzzle.burnPage(puzzle.getPages().get(0));
        assertEquals(i, puzzle.getToBurn());
    }

    @Test
    public void isSolved() {
        assertFalse(puzzle.isSolved());

        for (Image page : puzzle.getPages()){
            puzzle.burnPage(page);
        }
        assertTrue(puzzle.isSolved());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this error is due to missing an opengl context.
So the HeadlessApplication is really to enable server side access to library stuff like Vector2 when the server/vm doesn't have a graphics context or audio, so its a kind of bypass of normal context creation as server side typically would need libGDX maths and networking but not to render anything. So the crash in your case is because you need an openGL context when you load the file presumably because you bind to a texture, but you don't have an openGL context  in headless mode.

The idea of headless for unit testing is that you are testing headless (i.e. non-rendering) logic.

btw libGDX help is more readily available on the discord server here https://discord.com/channels/348229412858101762/1019870201505910845